# No tests found for given includes Error, when running Parameterized Unit test in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, junit, parameterized-unit-test

I have tried to run Parameterized Unit Tests in Android Studio, as shown below:

```java
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;  

import junit.framework.TestCase;    

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;  

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;    

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SmallTest
public class FibonacciTest extends TestCase {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 5}, {6, 8}
        });
    }   

    @Parameter // first data value (0) is default
    public /* NOT private */ int fInput;    

    @Parameter(value = 1)
    public /* NOT private */ int fExpected; 

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.calculate(fInput));
    }
}
```

The result is an error stating `No Test Run`. However, if I remove the Parameterized tests, and change them to individual tests, it works.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is not working? Ar Parameterized unit tests not supported in Android development yet?

Below is the error with stack trace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.example.......FibonacciTest]
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: No tests found for given includes: [com.example........FibonacciTest]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.NoMatchingTestsReporter.afterSuite(NoMatchingTestsReporter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.afterSuite(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.TestListenerAdapter.completed(TestListenerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.completed(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.TestMainAction.run(TestMainAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestExecuter.execute(DefaultTestExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:527)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 4.153 secs
No tests found for given includes: [com.example......FibonacciTest]
```

Comment: Please try making your Test class public. The compiler may be unable to find your test classes if that's the case. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 534, accepted):

Add to your build.gradle:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: As a reference from the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#using_junit5. The code above enables JUnit5 Platform to run the tests in your JVM project. Based on the dependencies or configuration the new Jupiter engine will execute those tests or if you need backward compatibility you can inject/configure Vintage (JUnit4) engine will do it.

Comment: In Gradle's Kotlin DSL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128729/2330228

Comment: Adding reference from another answer, for additional info. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58399663/5739950)

Comment: This seems not enough in my case

Comment: Silly  that this isn't taken care of when doing a migration from Maven to Gradle with `gradle init`. Another consideration is the order of `test` in `build.gradle`, as in where it appears in the file.

Comment: Note that this produces a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50619) when it's used inside the android target of a **Kotlin Multi-platform** project.

Comment: This is happing with me when I am both using useJUnitPlatform()
    useTestNG() in build.gradle file. It is only able to identify testng or junit, not both .What is the solution?

Comment: In my case I used "SampleProject" (upper camel case) when generating a project with gradle init, and it used that as the "package name" The fix was to change the package name to lowercase.

Answer (score 546):

If you're using JUnit 5+, make sure you import the `@Test` annotation from the correct library:

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

not

<strike>`import org.junit.Test`</strike>

Comment: But why? I have a Spring (not Spring Boot) project where org.junit.Test works just fine. But now I created a Boot project with Initializr and only org.junit.jupiter.api.Test works. Very confusing.

Comment: I spent 2 days to figure out, why my tests not working, checked build.gradle, all test dependencies but finally found the root cause by your anwser. Thank you for this.                              I think spring boot need to exclude jUnit 4 dependencies automatically. Let people get errors or issue instead of silently no test case running.

Answer (score 240):

I am using JUnit 4, and what worked for me is changing the IntelliJ settings for 'Gradle -> Run Tests Using' from 'Gradle (default)' to 'IntelliJ IDEA'.

[image]

Source of my fix: https://linked2ev.github.io/devsub/2019/09/30/Intellij-junit4-gradle-issue/

Comment: @logbasex my understanding is that the default IntelliJ setting somehow becomes 'stale', and makes IntelliJ target the wrong testing framework. The original page is in korean so I don't understand it fully.

Comment: That's "plan B", but Gradle won't rebuild that from scratch. Said otherwise, if you count on Gradle so someone else can use your project, don't do that, or make sure to push the IntelliJ project in your repo, but that defeats the purpose of using Gradle...

Comment: On Android Arctic Fox, there is no 'Run tests using' option.

Answer (score 70):

Adding

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

to the top level gave me the error "> Could not find method test() for arguments". Instead I had to add it to `testOptions` inside the `android` block

```
android {
    ...

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using `useJUnitPlatform()` produces a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50619) when it's used inside the android target of a **Kotlin Multi-platform** project.

Answer (score 51):

To add to already great and easy solution provided by [Przemek315](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648719/przemek315), the same config if you use Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 51):

Just in case this helps anybody, this happened to me on IntelliJ, and the case is, tests had been working before with Gradle but suddenly, next day some test stopped working giving this error.

What I did was:

1. Go to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> change "Run tests using" to "IntelliJ IDEA".
2. Run your test.
3. Go again to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> change "Run tests using" to "Gradle (default)".
4. Keep running your test, it is working now.

Doing this, I avoided having to change my local configuration or change Gradle files in the project.

[image]

Comment: For me it didn't work until I reloaded gradle project after this change. Open gradle tool window and there is a refresh button on the toolbar.

Comment: This happened to me when I forget to add 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine' to testRuntime. 
( test failed with : org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath)
Switching to IDEA engine covered this.

Answer (score 29):

I made the mistake of defining my test like this

```
class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun `test name`() = runBlocking {


        // something here that isn't Unit
    }
}
```

That resulted in `runBlocking` returning something, which meant that the method wasn't void and junit didn't recognize it as a test. That was pretty lame. I explicitly supply a type parameter now to run blocking. It won't stop the pain or get me my two hours back but it will make sure this doesn't happen again.

```
class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun `test name`() = runBlocking<Unit> { // Specify Unit


        // something here that isn't Unit
    }
}
```

Comment: I have spent 30 minutes on this thanks to you for saving me one and a half hour!

Answer (score 20):

**Kotlin DSL**: add to your build.gradle.kts

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Gradle DSL**: add to your build.gradle

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: That's without type-safe accessor, otherwise see solution that had already been given by skryvets (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125215/183575)

Comment: This solution for kotlin DSL works for me . And you need to put that in app/build.gradle.

Comment: Also added `testImplementation(kotlin("test"))` in dependencies, otherwise it's not enough.

Answer (score 19):

Add in build.gradle,

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and use class ***org.junit.jupiter.api.Test*** for **@Test**, instead of ***org.junit.Test***

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this... this was my problem just now. I was using org.junit.Test.

Answer (score 17):

Found a way to run the test in Android Studio. Apparently running it using Gradle Configuration will not execute any test. Instead I use JUnit Configuration. The simple way to do so is go to Select your Test Class to run and Right Click. Then choose Run. After that you'll see 2 run options. Select the bottom one (JUnit) as per the image[image]

(note: If you can't find 2 Run Configuration to select, you'll need to remove your earlier used Configuration (Gradle Configuration) first. That could be done by Clicking on the "Select Run/Debug Configuration" icon in the Top Toolbar.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone that is getting the error: `Expression 'test' cannot be invoked as a function` when adding the proposed solutions, try instead

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Works with a KMM setup in 2021.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using intellij and want to use gradle you need to add this to the dependencies section of build.gradle file:

```
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
```

Comment: Thank you. I was accidentally using `junit-platform-engine` instead of `junit-jupiter-engine` which apparently caused this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the `testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0")` declaration

Answer (score 11):

I recently faced this issue and after deep-dive, I got to find out that I was using `@Test` annotation from `junit` library. However, my `build.gradle` file declared another test library.

Therefore, when I used `@Test` annotation from **Test library** present in `build.gradle` then it worked.

Answer (score 10):

You could check if your method is private. Spent a lot of time fixing this dumb mistake ...

Answer (score 6):

For me, the cause of the error message

> No tests found for given includes

was having inadvertently added a `.java` test file under my `src/test/kotlin` test directory. Upon moving the file to the correct directory, `src/test/java`, the test executed as expected again.

Answer (score 5):

Hard to believe but the issue in my case was the wrong name for the package that I created for my test cases. It shouldn't contain uppercase letters. For example, these cases are not correct:
"PackageName"
"Packagename"
"packageName"

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar error in Intellij when using JUnit 4.

The fix was to **remove** from build.gradle.kts

```
    test {  useJUnitPlatform()  }
```

The result build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.0"
    application
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.5.31"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.0")
    implementation ("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.1.0")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.1")
}



kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(11)
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```

And the tests work fine

```kotlin
import org.junit.Assert


class MainKtTest1 {
    @org.junit.Test
    fun firstTest() {
        Assert.assertEquals("2*2=4", 2 * 2, 4)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem occurred when writing in Kotlin and using IDEA 2020.3. Despite proper entries in build.gradle.kts. It turned out that the problem was when generating test functions by IDEA IDE (Alt + Insert). It generates the following code:

```
@Test
   internal fun name () {
     TODO ("Not yet implemented")
   }
```

And the problem will be fixed after removing the "internal" modifier:

```
@Test
   fun name () {
     TODO ("Not yet implemented")
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

For JUnit 5, we should use import `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and also should use `@ExtendWith` instead of `@RunWith`.

Answer (score 3):

I added one string to the gradle build dependency list:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.0")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}
```

Rebuild gradle and everything works.

And remember to add the Test Files:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
```

Answer (score 2):

Allow Run tests for all sub-modules using Intellij IDEA by command or UI.

```
subprojects {
    withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the @Test library. At first I had imporetd org.junit.Test and I was getting this exception. Then I changed it to org.junit.jupiter.api.Test and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting this message due to a runtime error with Junit which wasn't at all visible from the output of the gradle test task execution. I've run into this for a couple reasons:

1. Including the `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher` dependency with a version that didn't match the junit version I was using
2. Having an entry in `META-INF/services` for a Junit test listener which I had commented out

You can try re-running with `--debug` and search for `FAILED` or `org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException`. In my second case, the exception was:

```
2020-10-20T11:34:26.517-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
2020-10-20T11:34:26.517-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 1 STARTED
2020-10-20T11:34:26.661-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] Gradle Test Executor 1 FAILED
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 1.
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.662-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:413)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.663-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener: Provider com.example.myproject.MyCommentedOutClass not found
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:94)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:67)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
2020-10-20T11:34:26.664-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]             ... 25 more
```

Notice that these are `DEBUG` logs. I didn't see anything helpful with just `--info`

Answer (score 1):

I use `@Test` annotiation of  `org.junit.Test` package, but I had the same problem. After adding `testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0")` on `build.gradle`, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Add platform runner in build.gralde
   => testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-runner', version: '1.7.0'
2. Anotate test class with @RunWith
   => @RunWith(JunitPlatform.class)

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I've added `@EnableJUnit4MigrationSupport` class annotation.

(Of course together with already mentioned gradle libs and settings)

Answer (score 1):

My set up is Android Studio, Junit 4, test with robolectric.

The problem was I added this `noverify` setting to app level build.gradle in attempt to solve `Java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type` from Android Studio run test with code coverage. (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3023)

[image]

Removing it fix the problem.

Comment: I have multimodule project, just kindly **forget** to add `robolectric.properties` file inside `test/resource` folder because i only enabling it for sdk 19 & 29.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue and I want to share my experience hope it may help other SO users that may have similar experiences.

I have tried `useJUnitPlatform()` on gradle and however they don't work for me.

At last I noticed that I did an auto convert from Java to Kotlin on the test class, which converted some of the `@Test` annotation to something like:

`@get:Test`

Apparently by removing/correcting these annotations, all tests worked and no more errors of `no tests found for given includes ...`

Just remove these "incorrect" annotations and no more changes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was solved by deleting `.idea` in the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case file and class name of the test didn't match, and that was the cause.

Eg. file name `SomeTest.kt` and class `class SomeNewTest { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally created an abstract class instead of regular class and added test there so it didn't run because no subclass was created from it.

was

```
abstract class MyTest {

   @Test
   fun test1() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

should be

```
class MyTest {

   @Test
   fun test1() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a career-ending error! ha  ha ha ha, glad you made a come back.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. In My case, I am using JUnit 5 with gradle 6.6. I am managing integration test-cases in a separate folder call *integ*. I have to define a new task in **build.gradle** file and after adding first line -> `useJUnitPlatform()` , My problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

When I use junit5, it's working. But every time I execute `gradle --clean`, I get  `Class not found` error. Then I add this to **build.gradle** to resolve my problem and I can still use junit4:

```
test {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add robolectric dependency to resolve this issue.

Comment: It was my case too.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a private method. Changing the access modifier to public helped me.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of what you did?

Comment: @akubi I would assume changing something like `@Test private void test()` to be `@Test public void test()`.  However, by simply switching to using JUnit5, this removes the use of access modifiers on tests, `@Test void test()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running my test class in Intellij and saw `No tests were found`. I had marked my test methods as `static` - removing this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of these solutions worked. The issue was a problematic dependency being imported — junit.vintage.

Adding `exclude group: “org.junit.vintage”, module: “junit-vintage-engine”` to my build.gradle fixed this.

Comment: Could you please specify the aexct line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: No tests found for given includes: [com.example........FibonacciTest]
```

Possibly that there is a class not found exception.
You can check exactly the package path of the test cases, to see if there are any errors with the folder structure. It should be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I encountered this error when trying out **Jetbrains' Kotlin Test JUnit** which is a Kotlin-specific testing library, an alternative to the Java's JUnit.

I encountered this error:

> Test Events were not received
> Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com...TextExample](--tests filter)

To rectify the error I followed [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html#add-the-code-to-test-it) on how to set-up *Jetbrains Kotlin Test JUnit* on `Intellij` using *Kotlin DSL*.

I did the following on `Android Studio`:

**Step 1 - Added this line to mydependencies:** i.e. inside `build.gradle.kts` **`(app-level)`** file

```
dependencies { 
...

testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
...

}
```

Don't mix the above dependency with the other  Kotilin-JUnit Libs to avoid ambiguity.

**Step 2 (Optional) - Added the test task block** i.e. inside `build.gradle(.kts)` **`(project-level)`** file: If for any reason you have to use this step then it has to be on the Android **Project Level** build.gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration ...

    plugins {
        id("com.android.application") apply false
        ....
    }
    
    // add this block on project-level build.gradle.kts
    tasks.withType<Test> {

        useJUnitPlatform()

    }
```

There is also another way that worked for me by adding this dependency using the latest Kotlin Version (*in Dec. 2023 it was 1.9.10*)

```
testImplementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.9.10")
```

This will allow you to use the JetBrains Kotlin Test like this:

```
import kotlin.test.Test

class TextExample {

  @Test
    fun  exampleTest(){

    val result =  2 + 2
    assert(result == 4)
    }
}
```

I noted something very strange with the `@Test` annotation highlight color between the Java's and Jetbrains' Kotlin JUnit Libraries as depicted below:

[image]

Anyway, the color doesn't worry me as long as the tests run as intended.

**PS**
If you come across a test error, it is advisable to first run the `ExampleUnitTest` that comes with the Android project and see if it will pass then fix it according to the error message.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding... Maybe will help someone else...

In my case, this problem happened because of a case difference in the namespace of the unit test. One letter was upper case instead of lower case (camelCase instead of camelcase).

Answer (score -1):

Writing `@ParameterizedTest` methods in Kotlin, I had to add the following dependency in my `build.gradle` file:

```java
dependencies {
   testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}
```

Apparently JUnit 5 separates out the unit testing API and the runtime engine, and you need to include both for it to pick up your unit tests.

Answer (score -2):

It helps to add: test {useJUnitPlatform()}
but you also need to have recent springBootVersion for me it worked with '2.4.5'