# Unresolved reference: junit

Tags: java, gradle, junit, libgdx, kotlin

I'm writing game using Kotlin and LibGDX framework. I'm new to testing. I have passed some basic tutorial how to create simple test. And how to configure gradle. I just clicked on class and choose create test.

But, when i try to build project i get an error:

```
e: /Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/core/src/test/test/BagelTest.kt: (1, 12): Unresolved reference: junit
e: /Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/core/src/test/test/BagelTest.kt: (2, 12): Unresolved reference: junit
e: /Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/core/src/test/test/BagelTest.kt: (6, 6): Unresolved reference: Test
e: /Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/core/src/test/test/BagelTest.kt: (8, 9): Unresolved reference: Assertions
e: /Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/core/src/test/test/BagelTest.kt: (11, 6): Unresolved reference: Test
e: /Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/core/src/test/test/BagelTest.kt: (13, 9): Unresolved reference: Assertions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileKotlin'.
```

BagelTest looks like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach


internal class BagelTest {


    @BeforeEach
    internal fun setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    internal fun passes() {
        assert(true)
    }
}
```

I guess that gradle doesn't see junit, but i followed all instructions. Maybe i missed something.

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'org.multi-os-engine:moe-gradle:1.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.51"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Bagel"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.2'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"
    apply plugin: "kotlin-android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"

    /*kotlin {
        experimental {
            coroutines 'enable'
        }
    }*/

    sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["/test"]

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:1.7.3"

        testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
//        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.2.7"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure gradle has actually downloaded junit? Try running `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies` in the command line to tell it to recheck those dependencies.

Comment: Did you try putting `BagelTest.kt` in `/core/src/test/kotlin/`?

Comment: Make sure that your test folder is in the main folder of the project.

Comment: I am using Android Studio 4.0 version and there is (test) package already in the android project it's a default package , I have put my kotlin test file there and there is no problem with it. I didn't run the file yet but there are no import errors for junit etc. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 9):

I've configured junit tests for libGdx+kotlin by following steps:

1. Create 'test' folder in the core project folder - it will be the root folder for test code files: [project-root]/core/test
2. Add junit dependencies in project main gradle.build file to the project(":core") section:

   ```
   project(":core") {
     ....
     dependencies {
       ...
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
       testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion"
      }
    }
   ```
3. Add test source set in [project-root]/core/build.gradle file, right under the 'sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]' line:

   ```
   sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ["test/"]
   ```
4. Now the [project-root]/core/test folder will be highlighted with green, which means that this folder is recognized as test source directory. Now you can place there a .kt file with simple junut test, for example:

   ```
   import org.junit.Test
   import kotlin.test.assertEquals

   class SimpleTest{

       @Test
       fun testEquals(){
           var b=true
           assertEquals(true,b)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I am using Android Studio 4.0 version and there is (test) package already in the android project it's a default package  , I have put my kotlin test file there and there is no problem with it. I didn't run the file yet but there are no import errors for junit etc. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: `testCompile` is deprecated, should be replaced with `testImplementation`

Answer (score 8):

In my case problem was I didn't import

```
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
```

Update May 2020: This should be placed in build.gradle's `dependencies { }`. As of Android Studio version 4 and current gradle version, the variable should be named $*version_kotlin* for gradle to properly re-sync.

Answer (score 3):

in app module's `build.gradle`

replace `testImplementation`
with
`androidTestImplementation`

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the kotlin version defined in `build.gradle.kts (project)` is the same as the [selected in the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62374153/5279996).

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21" apply false
}
```

If these versions are matting and still not working then proceed with the following steps:

---

1. Delete all cache folders including:

   - .gradle
   - .idea
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart...
3. Open any gradle file (settings.gradle.kts)
4. In the IDE at the top right click in `Link Gradle project`

[image: Link Gradle project]

5. Finally, specifies that JUnit 5 should be used to execute the tests

#### build.gradle.kts

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

*Note*: This behavior can be defined [by gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58125215/5279996) or [from the IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60270401/5279996)

---

It is very likely that if it worked and you have the dependencies it is a cache problem or gradle configuration.

GL

Comment: Invalidating Caches didn't worked for me, but deleting .gradle, .idea and the build folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1) remove `internal` word - it is not required

2) using simple `assert` method in tests is wrong - use methonds from `org.junit.Assert.*`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 4.0 version and there is (test) package already in the android project it's a default package , I have put my kotlin test file there and there is no problem with it. I didn't run the file yet but there are no import errors for junit etc. I hope this is helpful.